# Choosing an entry from each column of a matrix and taking their sum

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have an m x n matrix of real numbers. How can I find all the ways of picking one entry from each column such that their sum is greater than some threshold value? The naive way would be to check all m^n ways, but are there any clever ways to do this that reduce the complexity slightly? I'm guessing that you cannot break the O(m^n) bound, but maybe another algorithm can slightly reduce the constant in front?

Also, if this problem is in essence a well-known problem (or similar to one), please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Some small improvements:

1. If the threshold is high enough, there are some matrix entries that you will never pick, simply because no matter what other entries you pick from the other columns, it is impossible for the sum to be high enough. We can eliminate these in preprocessing.
2. As you are picking entries from left to right and you find that no matter how you choose the entries from the remaining columns, just quit.

---

**Edit**: I would like to get the positions of the selected values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm based on your improvements that runs only a constant factor longer than is necessary to write out all of the output.

Before beginning, sort within each column from greatest to least and compute suffix sums of the first row (i.e., scan right to left to determine, for each j, the max contribution of columns j..n).

Now do a recursive search with your pruning rule: for the current column, try the values from greatest to least and recurse, breaking out of the row loop if the maximum contribution of the remaining columns plus the sum so far is less than the threshold.

For the analysis, look at the recursion tree. Each leaf is a solution, which, being of size n, pays for every ancestor. There is constant overhead at each node.

If somehow you can consume each solution in sublinear time, perhaps by intertwining producer and consumer, there's another optimization that drops the computation to O(1) per instead of O(n) by detecting when it's necessary to take all of the maximums remaining. This is accomplished by sorting the columns by the gap between the greatest and second-greatest element; then, as soon as there is only one choice for a column going left to right, the others are forced too.

Answer (score 2):

Is the postion of the values selected on the matrix a concern, or you just want to know the values selected on each column for each path?
If it is option two then ordering the values in each column would allow you to truncate search as soon as a value on a column no longer satisfies it. e.g.:

8  7  4  9  2
5  6  4  8  2
3  3  2  3  1
2  2  2  1  1

suppose your threshold is 25, then as you pick 8, 7, 4, 3, 2 you can stop your search on the 4th and 5th column for values 8,7,4 of column 1, 2 and 3. And so on...

Comment: I would like to know the positions, but could we adapt your solution by having the entries also store their original position?

Comment: @blf Getting the position as well isn't difficult. Just have each cell be a class containing the value and the original position (and sort on value).

Comment: An optimization - store the maximum sum you can get from any column until the last column (as the sum of maximum values from each column). This will allow you to stop earlier by simply adding this value for the rest of the columns to the current sum and comparing it against the threshold.

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, that is how I implemented improvement #2 in my original question :)